# Add dynamic ID to each div, call those later

Tags: jquery

I have multiple menu generated, but they have different menu items and different positions in my content.

For each '.ff_ftmenu' and '.ff_ftmenu_block' there is a separate ID, so that ffmenu-0 for example would match.

I click '.ff_ftmenu_block #ffmenu-0' and '.ff_ftmenu #ffmenu-0' gets triggered and opens. That’s the idea. But how do I assign the 'ffmenu-' + index' to the loop so just that one will open?

```
  var tl = new TimelineMax({paused:true, reversed:true});
  tl
    .staggerFromTo('.ff_ftmenu li', 1.5,
      {rotationX:-90, transformOrigin:"50% 0%"},
      {rotationX:0, ease:Elastic.easeOut}, 0.4);

  $('.ff_ftmenu').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('id', 'ffmenu-' + index);
    //console.log( this.id );
  });

  $('.ff_ftmenu_block').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('id', 'ffmenu-' + index);
  });

  $('.ff_ftmenu_block').each(function(index){
    $(this).click(function(index){
    $('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu').toggleClass('open');

      if (!$('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu').hasClass('open')) {
        TweenMax.to($('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu'), 0.5, {opacity: 0});
        tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.pause(0).reversed(true);
      }
      else {
        TweenMax.to($('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu'), 1, {opacity: 1});
        tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.pause(0).reversed(true);
      }

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery in this case to get the element where you clicked on you don't need each.  So I think you can replace

```
$('.ff_ftmenu_block').each(function(index){
$(this).click(function(index){
$('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu').toggleClass('open');

  if (!$('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu').hasClass('open')) {
    TweenMax.to($('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu'), 0.5, {opacity: 0});
    tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.pause(0).reversed(true);
  }
  else {
    TweenMax.to($('.swp-col-1-3 .ff_ftmenu'), 1, {opacity: 1});
    tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.pause(0).reversed(true);
  }

});
```

with (just to give you a starting - point - idea)

```
$('.ff_ftmenu_block').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id');
    // move on from here with the id
    // and do whatever you want to do
});
```